# remove an item from one list and store it into the end of another list

Tags: python, list

I am making a simple card game in python in which players compare a stat of a card, the card with the higher stat value wins the round and the loser gives them that card, removing it from their deck and putting it into the end of the winners deck.

Here is my code for the game which includes a round of gameplay:

```
import random
   class Ram():
        def __init__(self, name, weight, milk, wool, offs, thigh, fert, meat, fat):
           self.name = name
           self.weight = weight
           self.milk = milk
           self.wool = wool
           self.offs = offs
           self.thigh = thigh
           self.fert = fert
           self.meat = meat
           self.fat = fat

       def __repr__(self):
           return f"{self.name,self.weight,self.milk,self.wool,self.offs,self.thigh,self.fert,self.meat,self.fat}"


def Read(txtfile):
    datalist=[]
    f = open(txtfile, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    for line in f:
        datalist.append(line.split(','))
    f.close()
    cardlist = []
    for i in datalist:
        cardlist.append(Ram(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6], i[7]))
    return cardlist

def RandomChoice():
   l=["User","Computer"]
   return random.choice(l)

 cardlist=Read("hrutaspil.txt")

 random.shuffle(cardlist)
 split = len(cardlist) // 2

user_deck = cardlist[:split]
computer_deck = cardlist[split:]


game=input("Do you want to play?(y/n)")
if game == "y":
    if RandomChoice() == "User":
       print("The user chooses first")
       print("Your top card is:",user_deck[0].name)
       print("1 = weight =",user_deck[0].weight)
       print("2 = milk =", user_deck[0].milk)
       print("3 = wool =", user_deck[0].wool)
       print("4 = offs =", user_deck[0].offs)
       print("5 = thigh =", user_deck[0].thigh)
       print("6 = fert =", user_deck[0].fert)
       print("7 = meat =", user_deck[0].meat)
       print("8 = fat =", user_deck[0].fat)
       choice=input("Choose stat: ")
       if choice == ("1"):
          print("Weight is:",float(user_deck[0].weight))
          print("compared with computer:",float(computer_deck[0].weight))
          if float(computer_deck[0].weight) > float(user_deck[0].weight):
             print("Computer wins.")
          else:
             print("You win.")
```

Now, how do I remove a card from the losers deck and add it to the bottom of the winners deck?

Comment: The section of the documentation on data structures will have your answer (don't worry, it's short, clear, and has clear examples): https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: look up lists, pop(), slicing syntax and insert() - a combination of any of these will bring you there.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a stack?  Python lists act as stacks, so you can `pop` elements off the top of each deck, then use `insert(0, card)` to put the card at the bottom of the winning deck.

Answer (score 0):

```
if float(computer_deck[0].weight) > float(user_deck[0].weight):
    print("Computer wins.")
    computer_deck.append(user_deck.pop(0))
else:
    print("You win.")
    user_deck.append(computer_deck.pop(0))
```

Are you also aware that the user wins ties? I'm not sure that's what you intended based on reading your question.